# Html imput type="image" onclick event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Friends I have a problem
We need to make a user control that has the ability to delete itself, I made it but we did not clear the mechanism for removal, it should be tied to a nice picture. Code that is attached to the frame is given below, but not

```
        $('#delete').bind('click', function () {

    alert('test');
        var urlA = '<%=Url.Action("DeleteMessage","Ticket")%>';
        $.ajax({
            url: urlA,
            type: 'POST',

            data: { idMessage:$(this).parents("div:first").find("input[name='MessageID']").val(),idticket:$('#TicketID').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

But when I write this, but to throw me to the homepage what's wrong

```
    $('#delete').live('click', function ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#delete").live("click", function(){
    //code
    $(this).remove(); //delete itself
});
```

Comment: I must call action methode with click?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in favour of `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()`

Comment: I SOLVED PROBLEM MY SOLUTION IS

Comment: $("#allMessages").delegate("#delete", "click", function(){

Answer (score 0):

If your image is declared as input type="image" then it will behave like a submit button and submit your page.  You should prevent the default behavior of submitting the page by adding an event.preventDefault() or equivalent to your javascript function.